# Umbraco member properties

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco8

I got the below error,

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
>   'IEnumerable'

This is my code,

```
var member = Members.GetCurrentMember();
        if (member!=null) { 
        string redirectURL = (member.Properties["postSignInUrl"].Value.ToString() != null ) ? member.Properties["postSignInUrl"].Value.ToString() : "";
        Response.Redirect(redirectURL);
```

I am trying to get the members property value of postSignInUrl which is custom

Comment: what does GetCurrentMember returns?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Umbraco issue per se. Its hard to tell what GetCurrentMember() returns as its a var here.

`IEnumerable` doesnot include an [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/index). [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx) include Indexing. If the method returns an `IList<T>`, then make a reference of type `IList<T>` else use `enumerable.ElementAt(index)`.